# Como gerar um Array de Objeto JavaScript de forma dinâmica

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json, angular, lógica

Estou querendo "montar" um array de objeto JSON com dados provindos do banco de dados, mas surgiram alguns desafios.

Tenho o seguinte campo de seleção com um método que é chamado toda vez que o valor é alterado - (change)='generateJSON()':

```
<form [formGroup]='productForm' class="mt-4" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="ProductName" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Nome do produto">Product Name <small>(POF)</small></label>
            <small *ngIf="productName != null && productName?.ProductInfos != null">
                <a [href]="productName?.ProductInfos" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">- Intranet ({{ productName?.ProductName | reducedName:25 }})</a>
            </small>
            <ng-select id="ProductName" autofocus (change)="generateJSON()"
                class="isRequired ajustar"
                [items]="productNames"
                [selectOnTab]="true"
                bindLabel="ProductName"
                dropdownPosition="auto"
                labelForId="AccountOwner"
                placeholder="Search a product"
                [virtualScroll]="true"
                formControlName="ProductName">
                    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
                        <div><span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ item.ProductName }}</span></div>
                    </ng-template>
            </ng-select>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Método generateJSON():

```
public generateJSON(): void {
        this.product = this.productForm.get('ProductName').value;

        this.productHierarchyService.getDataForJSON(this.product.id)
            .subscribe(
                productHierarchy => this.productHierarchy = productHierarchy,
                err => console.log(err),
                () => this.pof_json()
            )
    }
```

Toda vez que o valor do campo de seleção é alterado é feita uma consulta no banco de dados trazendo todas as configurações possíveis para um produto.
Algo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método pof_json() tem a função de criar o JSON de forma dinâmica.
Gostaria que o JSON seguisse a seguinte estrutura.

```
POF = [
    {
        "ID":"ID_POE",
        "POE_NAME":"POE_NAME",
        "ATTRIBUTES": [
            {
                "ID":"ID_ATTR",
                "ATTR_NAME":"ATTR_NAME",
                "VALUE": [
                    {
                        "ID":"ID_VALUE",
                        "VALUE_NAME":"VALUE_NAME"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Como pode ver, a variável POF é um array de objetos javascript podendo ter um ou mais POE. E cada POE pode ter um ou mais Atributos e, finalmente, cada atributo pode ter um ou mais valores.

Mas um dos problemas é retirar as informações repetidas, pois, como pode ser visto na imagem do banco de dados, há 233 linhas, mas na verdade são apenas 3 POE's diferentes e 4 atributos diferentes.

E outro desafio seria associar corretamente os valores de POE, Atributos e Valores. Exemplo: POE -> AC CIRCUIT possui 2 atributos e cada atributo possuem seus respectivos valores.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

EDIT 1:
valor retorno pelo this.productHierarchy

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em ".subscribe(productHierarchy => this.productHierarchy = productHierarchy", você poderia colocar o valor retornado em "productHierarchy" ?

Comment: Adicionei o que você pediu.
O retorno vai depender do que eu selecionar no campo select

Comment: Eu queria era os dados em json/txt e não o print, pois no print não consigo ver/manipular o objeto todo. Ex: [ { POD_ID: 1, POF: "POF 1" ... }, { POD_ID: 2, POF: "POF 2" ... } , { POD_ID: 3, POF: "POF 3" ... } ].

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-QZBNi7QxPoeffE_aE2SvfeKPOgQZTfM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: se deu certo, aceita como resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Estou testando o código agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("Relacionamentos.json", function(data) {
  var POE_IDs = data
    .map(x => x.POE_ID)
    .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);

  var test = POE_IDs
    .reduce(
      (a, c) => {

        var ATTRIBUTES = data
          .filter(x => x.POE_ID == c)
          .map(x => x.ATTR_ID)
          .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);


        return a.concat({
          ID: c,
          POE_NAME: data.find(x => x.POE_ID == c).POE,
          ATTRIBUTES: ATTRIBUTES.reduce((a2, c2) => a2.concat({
            ID: c2,
            ATTR_NAME: data.find(x => x.POE_ID == c && x.ATTR_ID == c2).ATTR,
            VALUE: data.filter(x => x.POE_ID == c && x.ATTR_ID == c2).reduce((a3, c3) => a3.concat({
              ID: c3.VALUES_ID,
              VALUE: c3.VALUES
            }), [])
          }), [])
        })
      }, []);

      console.log(test);
});
```

Da uma olhada aqui, ver o retorno no console.log: [teste](https://plnkr.co/edit/B0bKDWiqxx1EUQGxYhbC?p=preview)

Comment: Funcionou muito bem RDyego. Obrigado.
Não entendi muita coisa do que foi feito no código, mas vou buscar aprender.
Complexidade acima do meu conhecimento atual.

Novamente, obrigado.